# Actuator creation of shapes governed by rubber mass

Tags: actuator

Let's start with **hyposurface** by Mark Goulthorpe. Essentially this is what is required but for a different application.

**Objectives**.
To know if its probable or possible to link up to 200 number x 300mm stroke, 12v feedback potentiometer actuators together to work in synchronisation but also independently to follow programmed movements.

**Outcome**.
Creation of digital shapes, working in tandem both independently and as a collective final outcome, determined by an external program, to perform real world physical movements such as:
TILT: left to right, right to left, back to front and front to back.
CURVE: creation of single curve, double curves, both concave and convex and finally free form curves.

**SETTING**
Set underneath and fixed into a solid, stable framework with a stretched, tensioned, one inch rubber surface fitted and fixed on top of each actuator to allow for the creation of the shapes set out by the program.

*This is early stage development and requires answers from experienced and knowledgeable engineers to first determine if like Hyposurface this can be created but to a much greater degree of structural bonding and rigidity.*

Comment: Yes, just need a set of controllers to be programmed to control the actuators based on the shape to be displayed.